# How to implement OData federation for Application integration

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I have to integrate various legacy applications with some newly introduced parts that are silos of information and have been built at different times with varying architectures. At times these applications may need to get data from other system if it exists and display it to the user within  their own screens based on the business needs.

I was looking to see if its possible to implement a generic federation engine that kind of abstracts the aggregation of the data from various other OData endpoints and have a single version of truth.

An simplistic example could be as below.

[image: Data Federation using OData]

I am not really looking to do an ETL here as that may introduce some data related side effects in terms of staleness etc.

Can some one share some ideas as to how this can be achieved or point me to any article on the net that shows such a concept.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: You haven't given a lot of detail, but in analyzing an approach, I might question if the services (OData) layer is the correct layer for achieving a service bus or [Hub and Spoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd459147(v=sql.100).aspx) architecture. Most likely each OData service is a layer above individual business logic and/or data persistence layers. Perhaps pursue aggregation at that level, and allow OData to remain as the more functional but lightweight service front-end?

Comment: @mdisibio : that's correct, each of these applications already exposes the OData over some business logic and may introduce some data security like who is allowed to see some part of data transparently. I also need this to be on OData as some of these systems are not on SQL database. So the intent is that when an Order is being placed, it may try to get the customer details from CRM to check what kind of discounts can be provided. if CRM system is not present, it may just skip that.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, the answer is to use either the reflection provider or a custom provider.

- [Support for multiple data sources (odata)](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1054805-support-for-multiple-data-sources-odata-)
- [Allow me to expose entities from multiple sources](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1012629-allow-me-to-expose-entities-from-multiple-sources)

To decide between the two approaches, take a look at [this article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx).

If you decide that you need to build a custom provider, the referenced article also contains links to a series of other articles that will help you through the learning process.

Your project seems non-trivial, so in addition I recommend looking at other resources like the [WCF Data Services Toolkit](https://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/) to help you along.

By the way, from an architecture standpoint, I believe your idea is sound. Yes, you may have some domain logic behind OData endpoints, but I've always believed this logic should be thin as OData is primarily used as part of data access layers, much like SQL (as opposed to service layers which encapsulate more behavior in the traditional sense). Even if that thin logic requires your aggregator to get a little smart, it's likely that you'll always be able to get away with it using a custom provider.

That being said, if the aggregator itself encapsulates a lot of behavior (as opposed to simply aggregating and re-exposing raw data), you should consider using another protocol that is less data-oriented (but keep using the OData backends in that service). Since domain logic is normally heavily specific, there's very rarely a one-size-fits-all type of protocol, so you'd naturally have to design it yourself.

However, if the aggregated data is exposed mostly as-is or with essentially structural changes (little to no behavior besides assembling the raw data), I think using OData again for that central component is very appropriate.

Obviously, and as you can see in the comments to your question, not everybody would agree with all of this -- so as always, take it with a grain of salt.